# Mismatch between inequalities in proof for set balancing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

I had a lecture today, where a chernoff bound was used to find a bound for the infinity norm of a $n \times n$ binary matrix $A$ and a vector of $b \in \{-1, 1\}^n$. There is a step in the proof

[image]

Now without going into unnecessary detail $k \leq n$. But what i dont understand is that, if the first probability is $< 1/n^2$ and we make that probability harder to obtain by swapping $k$ with $n$, how can we be sure that the second probability still is $<1/n^2$? Is this not a mismatch between the inequalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your "first probability" is the one with $k$.

One way to to look at it: If the first probability $< 1/n^2$ (what you assumed), and second probability $\le$ first probability (since $k \le n$), then second prob $\le$ first prob $< 1/n^2$.  What's the problem?

Another way to look at it: If the first prob $< 1/n^2$, for all $k \le n$, then it particular it is true for $k=n$, thus the second prob also $< 1/n^2$.

So there is no issue if the first prob $< 1 / n^2$.  However, note that the quoted line in no way states that first prob $< 1/ n^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know. It was a brain fart during finals revision haha.